# network statistics monthly group by ip address

Tags: linux, router, network-monitoring

How can I get network statistics monthly group by ip address on my linux router.

I have a linux router at home and I want to get  network statistics information monthly grouped by ip address pair like this:

```
192.168.1.x -> x.x.x.x  ??? Bytes 
y.y.y.y1 -> 92.168.1.y  ??? Bytes
```

I perfer free software and not forbid to do some development myself.
I found I could use TUN/TAP or libpcap to get packets. 
But thinking of the performance and processes synchronization , I need some suggestion.

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't there already something like Nethogs or iptraf for that?

Answer (score 0):

Use pure iptables.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.100
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.101
...
```

Then write a script which reads the counters from netfilter with using iptables.

```
iptables -L FORWARD -vxn                                     
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 454 packets, 315224 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
     173   140480            all  --  *  *       1.2.3.4        0.0.0.0/0
```

And put this script to `/etc/cron.monthly/`.

Comment: According to the original question's sample output they want to track the source and destination which your methods doesn't do.  Also adding iptables entries for every possible ip they use would hurt performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
ipset create track_hosts hash:net,net family inet hashsize 262144 maxelem 333000 counters comment
```

If you run out of entries in a month increase the 333000 to bigger number.

```
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING 1 -j SET  --add-set track_hosts src,dst
```

You may also add **-i eth0** between the 1 and the -j to limit it to 1 network adapter.

---

```
ipset save track_host
```

will immediately have results

```
add track_hosts 192.168.3.220,192.168.3.2 packets 1 bytes 60
add track_hosts 192.168.3.251,192.168.3.2 packets 1 bytes 1356
add track_hosts 192.168.3.248,233.89.188.1 packets 1 bytes 186
add track_hosts 192.168.3.222,192.168.3.2 packets 1 bytes 40
add track_hosts 192.168.3.248,239.255.255.250 packets 1 bytes 441
add track_hosts 192.168.3.249,255.255.255.255 packets 1 bytes 186
```

Statistic are no good if not saved between reboots.

If your router has systemd:
note change the file path to suite your needs -f /src/all.txt

```
[Unit]
Description=IP sets for iptables
After=ufw.service
Before=network.target
Before=iptables.service
Before=webmin-iptables.service
AssertPathExists=/src/all.txt

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStartPre=-/bin/echo 'Loading ipset sets'
ExecStart=/sbin/ipset restore -f /src/all.txt
ExecStop=/sbin/ipset save -f /src/all.txt
ExecStartPost=-/bin/echo 'Saving ipsets to disk'
#ExecReload=/usr/libexec/ipset/ipset.start-stop reload
# Save current ipset entries on stop/restart.
#   Value: yes|no,  default: no
# Saves all ipsets to /etc/sysconfig/ipset if ipset gets stopped
Environment=IPSET_SAVE_ON_STOP=yes IPSET_SAVE_ON_RESTART=no
ReadWriteDirectories=/src
NoNewPrivileges=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

Please change the path first. Restoring iptables can be done this way

```
[Unit]
Description=IPtables load rules
DefaultDependencies=no
After=ipset.service network-pre.target
Before=network-online.target network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=-/bin/echo 'Starting iptables'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/iptables-restore /etc/webmin/firewall/iptables.save
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/iptables-restore /etc/webmin/firewall/iptables.save
#ExecStop=/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/iptables-flush
ExecStopPost=-/bin/echo 'Flushing iptables'
RemainAfterExit=yes
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_RAW

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

Now all that is left in a cronjob to

```
ipset save -f /somewhere/month-year && ipset --flush track_hosts
```

The first half save the statistics, and the second half clears them to start the new month over fresh.  Of course, you don't have to flush if you don't want to.

You can parse the output the way you want like this.

```
ipset save track_hosts|sed 's/.*track_hosts //'|sed 's/,/ -> /'|sed 's/packets [0-9].//'
```

---

```
cat month-year|sed 's/.*track_hosts //'|sed 's/,/ -> /'|sed 's/packets [0-9].//'
```

The end results:

```
192.168.3.220 -> 192.168.3.2 bytes 60
192.168.3.2 -> 239.255.255.253 bytes 105
192.168.3.251 -> 192.168.3.2 bytes 1356
192.168.3.248 -> 233.89.188.1 bytes 186
192.168.3.222 -> 192.168.3.255 bytes 78
216.17.8.11 -> 192.168.3.2 bytes 40
192.168.3.222 -> 192.168.3.2 bytes 40
```